# Prestashop: Custom vouchers based on weight (PHP)

Tags: php, prestashop, prestashop-1.7

I'm working in a prestashop store for a client. He wants to focus on the clothes weight to set the price so I've modified all the tpl files needed to display this attribute accordingly. However, I'm experimenting some issues to find an approach to generate custom vouchers based on the total cart weight.

The idea is when a customer reach, in example, 0.5 kg, he or she automatically gets a discount code. Difficult here is that PS/Settings only set vouchers based on price rules. I thought that maybe I could work with a php or tpl backend file but vouchers are related with the database. Taking all in consideration I'm wondering if some of you have tried this kind of modifications and could advice me about what files I should be working with and what kind of code functions a I will need.

Thank you in advance!!

Comment: Welcome to Stackoverflow! Please, could you provide a minimal reproducible example? We are glad to help if you give us the tools, in this case the code of what you've done so far.

Comment: Did you ever figured it out?